# Write permission issues Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, 18.04, ntfs, drive

**OS**: Ubuntu 18.04 (**Multi-boot** (`Windows-10,Manjaro,Ubuntu`))
I have a **NTFS** partition with a size of  `500 GB`. I can't do any kind of write operations on that `NTFS Partition`. I think this behaviour showed up after I installed `Manjaro` OS

#### Screenshots

[image: Image 1]

**UPDATE-1**
I run `mount | grep sda7` and got output as below

```
/dev/sda7 on /media/jpg/MyDrive type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Comment: How did you mount the partition? Please post the output of the `mount` command. You should also check [existing questions regarding NTFS write problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=ntfs+cannot+write+site%3Aaskubuntu.com).

Comment: I mounted the partition using GUI.

Comment: @Melebius Updated the question (**UPDATE-1** section)

Comment: it looks like you the mount option read only set. do you have a file `/etc/exports`?

Comment: No,  I don't have :(